# Difference of LINQ .Aggregate with result selector parameter or directly calling method

Tags: c#, linq, fold

Is there a practical difference when using the LINQ [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548744%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method by passing a resultSelector function or by directly passing the `Aggregate` result value to the function?

Code example (there's better way to do that, but this illustrates the problem pretty well):

```
var list = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
list.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, s) => sb.AppendLine(s), sb => sb.ToString());
list.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, s) => sb.AppendLine(s)).ToString();
```

In the end, both statements return the same string.
Is there code that can be written one way, but not the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no difference. Looking at my [Edulinq](http://edulinq.googlecode.com) implementation, I've implemented the overload without the selector just by calling the overload *with* a selector, and then with an identity transformation:

```
public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func)
{
    return source.Aggregate(seed, func, x => x);
}
```

It would have been perfectly reasonable to do it the other way round, e.g.

```
public static TResult Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func,
    Func<TAccumulate, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    var intermediate = source.Aggregate(seed, func);
    return resultSelector(intermediate);
}
```

Now just because they're equivalent doesn't mean the overload is useless. For example, sometimes it could be easier to express the result selector using a lambda expression:

```
var result = list.Aggregate(..., ..., total => total < 0 ? total + 1
                                                         : total - 1);
```

You could create a separate method (or just a `Func<TArg, TResult>`) to do that, but in some cases you want to do the whole thing in a single method call.

In short - use whichever approach is most convenient for you in each individual case; they're equivalent as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Exactly! [The actual implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ff1369203d6036a4) shows that the last line `return resultSelector(result);` doesn't depend on any condition, so it's just the same as doing it afterwards.